# Open modal with ReactJS (es6) and siblings components

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, react-bootstrap, react-alt

I have my app component with a Navbar component, and a ModalLogin component.

App component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar history={this.props.history} />
        {this.props.children}
        <ModalLogin />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Navbar component

```
class Navbar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = NavbarStore.getState();
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    NavbarStore.listen(this.onChange);
  }

  onChange(state) {
   this.setState(state);
  }

  render() {
   return (
     <nav className='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top'>
        <ul className='nav navbar-nav'>
           <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
  )
 }
```

And the ModalLogin uses react-bootstrap:

```
 render() {
    return (
     <div>
      <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={ModalLoginActions.close}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
      </Modal.Body>
     </Modal>
  )
}
```

But as you can see, Navbar and Modal are siblings in my app. Is this the correct way?

Comment: Looks ok. Is there any problem you are facing?

Comment: yeah! <li><a href="#">Login</a></li> should have some onClick which fires modal display, but don't know how!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write an onClick handler that triggers an event in the parent.

```
render() {
   return (
     <nav className='navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top'>
        <ul className='nav navbar-nav'>
           <li><a href="#" onClick={this.props.onLogin}>Login</a></li>
        </ul>
     </nav>
  )
```

Add a handler to the App component which sets showModal state to true.

```
<Navbar 
  history={this.props.history} 
  onLogin={() => this.setState({showModal: true})}
/>
```

Pass the showModal to the ModalLogin component.

```
<ModalLogin showModal={this.state.showModal} />
```

Within the ModalLogin, use the props to show the Modal.

```
Modal show={this.props.showModal} onHide={ModalLoginActions.close}>
```

Comment: But their parent is App. Is it correct or should i handle it from there?

Comment: If LoginModal is triggered only from NavBar, put it within NavBar component. Else move it to App.